# Dell Vostro 1510 WiFi Problem

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, kubuntu, broadcom

I have an old laptop,Dell Vostro 1510. I needed to install Kubuntu 14.04.3 on it. It doesn't recognize the wireless.
I entered:

lspci -nn | grep 0280

in a terminal, as @chili555 suggested in question 547746 right here in ask ubuntu, and the outcome is:

```
0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
```

Kubuntu 14.04 recognized wireless while live.
I know there are some questions exactly about this on www.askubuntu.com but none have reached an end.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to connect to internet by wire and run

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Answer (score -1):

Open source drivers have some issues with this card. The official drivers should work.
Download the binary file from [here](https://www.broadcom.com/support/?gid=1). It must be one of the first two depending on your architecture. 
After download,

```
tar -xvf /path/to/archive
make
make install
```

This should work.

Comment: This driver does not support this adapter. And there is no need to install it from source anyway.

Comment: The driver supports BCM4312. This adapter is giving some extra trouble I don't know why. I am not sure if it is supported by any driver in official repo.

Comment: It is supported by `b43`